# Semantic HTML element representing an UI widget

Tags: html, widget, semantic-markup

**Is there an element in HTML that represents an UI widget?**

I wonder if any of the semantic HTML elements is designed for widgets like draggable clocks, weather forecasts or address book contacts?

I’m not sure if `<aside>` makes sense for an interactive UI element and whether `<dialog>` is intended for anything other than a modal dialog or if I should stick to `<section>` or even `<div>`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is: By definition, the [**`<article>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article) element is designed for, among other things, representing an interface widget.

The [W3C specifies](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element):

> The **article element** represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be <sub><sup>( … )</sup></sub> an **interactive widget** or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

That fits well with the [Wikipedia definition of “widget”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget#In_computing):

> - a generic type of software application comprising portable code intended for one or more different software platforms
> - a reusable element of a graphical user interface